# Composer Function to Bind Sequence of Callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, bind

StackOverflow community. I'm trying to create a function that will compose a sequence of callbacks, so that I can run them in the correct order.

```
function Number1 (callback) {
   do something...
   callback();
}

function Number2 (callback) {
   do something...
   callback();
}

function Number3 (callback) {
   do something...
   callback();
}
```

If we think of it as an array of functions, each callback function receives the next function as it's own callback. i.e.: Function Number1 receives Function Number2 as its callback which, in turn, receives Function Number3 as its callback, and so on and so forth.

So, for the function:

```
RunThem(callbacks) {
   ...
}

RunThem(Number1, Number2, Number3);
```

The composed result should be like this:

```
Number1.bind(this, Number2.bind(this, Number3))
```

Is there a way to do this with currying or a similar approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. You could use `reduceRight` for that:

```
const func = callbacks.reduceRight(
   // not sure what you want `this` to refer to, so using `null` instead
  (func, callback) => callback.bind(null, func)
);
```

```js
function noop() {}

function runThem(...callbacks) {
  callbacks.reduceRight(
    (func, callback) => callback.bind(null, func),
    noop
  )();
}

function Number1 (callback) {
   console.log(1);
   callback();
}

function Number2 (callback) {
   console.log(2);
   callback();
}

function Number3 (callback) {
   console.log(3);
   callback();
}

runThem(Number1, Number2, Number3);
```

You can also completely avoid `.bind` and work of the stack off functions instead:

```js
function runThem(...callbacks) {
  callbacks.shift()(function run() {
    if (callbacks.length > 0) {
      callbacks.shift()(run);
    }
  });
}

function Number1 (callback) {
   console.log(1);
   callback();
}

function Number2 (callback) {
   console.log(2);
   callback();
}

function Number3 (callback) {
   console.log(3);
   callback();
}

runThem(Number1, Number2, Number3);
```

Comment: You may want to include if(callback) callback(); checks just in case they are undefined.

Comment: @Esaith: Just using the OPs code. I added a `noop` function in the first example, and the second one works as is.

Comment: Awesome! I considered using reduce but, since it's left-to-right, I discarded it right away. Now I know reduceRight thanks to you!